# How to get real time output of script, written in %post section of RPM .spec file?

Tags: linux, bash, yum, rpm, centos-7

Good day. Problem:
In a %post install section of RPM spec file can be a script.
I want to put there a script with a realtime output, like progress bar for post-installation process. But all output produced by commands in this section is strongly buffered by (i suppose) Yum, and showed only when section is completely executed.
Question: is there a way to get output, produced by scripts inside of %post sections (python or pure pash scripts) imidiately or asap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RPM is noninteractive. You really should not produce any output like progress bar. It will just confuse tools built on top of rpm. And it will very likely lead to some other errors.

Comment: @msuchy I know that is sort of bad idea. But at least i don't try to do realy interactive things, like getting user input. Main installation part of my RPM was drowned into %post install script, so it was important to see progress and errors occuring during %post.
As i discovered later, it's possible to do output in stderr. It's not bufferized like stdout. Anyway, already rerouted my output to log file. Thanks for a reply!

Comment: Although the original poster mentioned a `stderr` workaround, `yum` 3.4.3 seems to buffer `stderr` as well.

Comment: There are very good reasons for showing output during an RPM installation.  The fact that RPM is "noninteractive" has no relevance.  If one of the scriptlets (pre, post, etc) takes a long time the user should get periodic updates in order to know that the process hasn't stalled.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `stdout` of your script to the `stdout` of its parent process. Similarly for `stderr`.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>/proc/$PPID/fd/1
exec 2>/proc/$PPID/fd/2
```

Redirecting `stdout` like this could have unintended consequences or give a nasty surprise to someone running the script trying to capture and parse its `stdout` when that output appears in their terminal anyway.

You can see how this might be confusing (imagine its running on a script not a `-c` argument)

```
$ x=$(bash -c 'exec 1>/proc/$PPID/fd/1 && echo text')
text
$ echo "x was $x"
x was
```

Firstly, something printed even though the subshell should have captured stdout! And then, `x` was empty! Madness. It looks like the `text` came from a `stderr`, except it didn't.

Ideally `yum` would just have a flag for this; maybe someone should make a pull request ;)

Comment: I should probably admit that even though I warned this is a bad idea I do actually always use it in my own rpm scripts now...

Comment: Bonus hack: Use `ps --no-headers -o ppid:1` and iterate through the output fds until you find one for which `dirname $(realpath /proc/$PID/fd/1) == "/dev/pts"` - Then no matter what, your output will always annoy someone.

Answer (score 0):

use redirection to /dev/tty:

```
program >/dev/tty
```